# SQL Query in looking at first two records of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have an employee table for salary/rate history.  It looks like...

```
Employee#    EffectDate     Salary
00016        2014-01-03     78100.00
00016        2013-07-03     75130.00
00016        2013-01-06     72140.00
00114        2014-07-15     85610.00
00244        2014-01-10     54130.00
00244        2013-06-30     50140.00
00634        2013-12-25     72560.00
00634        2013-04-05     69348.00
00634        2012-01-01     64530.00
```

I am trying to get one row for employee that shows current salary, last effective date, and immediate last salary...

```
Employee#    CurrentSalary   LastChange    PreviousSalary
00016        78100.00        2014-01-03    75130.00
00114        85610.00        2014-07-15    NULL
00244        54130.00        2014-01-10    50140.00
00634        72560.00        2013-12-25    69348.00
```

Using Microsoft SQL 2012

Comment: do you ask us to write SQL query for you?

Comment: What code have you tried?  SO is not a code outsourcing community.

Comment: Why are you against aggregation (per your comments)?  Multiple correlated subqueries are surely slower than a single aggregated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick variant from the top of my head:

```
select
    t.Employee,
    (select top 1 Salary
        from table as a
        where a.Employee = t.Employee and a.EffectDate = t.LastChange
        order by EffectDate desc) as CurrentSalary,
    t.LastChange,
    (select top 1 Salary
        from table as a
        where a.Employee = t.Employee and a.EffectDate < t.LastChange
        order by EffectDate desc) as PreviousSalary
from (
    select Employee, max(EffectDate) as LastChange
    from table
    group by Employee) as t
```

Comment: Thanks.  Simple and works with having to partition table within my current SQL query.  The Select Top 1 with the AND clause is where I went wrong.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `row_number` with `max` and `case` (a form of pivoting):

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by employeenum order by effectdate desc) rn
  from salary
  )
select employeenum,
  max(case when rn = 1 then salary end) currentsalary,
  max(case when rn = 1 then effectdate end) lastchange,
  max(case when rn = 2 then salary end) previoussalary
from cte
group by employeenum
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44fe8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using a `CTE`, you can get a `ROW_NUMBER()` by partitioning and then using this Row Number in the query.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    EmployeeId    VARCHAR (20)  ,
    EffectiveDate DATE          ,
    salary        DECIMAL (8, 2));

INSERT  INTO @tbl (EmployeeId, EffectiveDate, salary)
VALUES           (00016, getdate(), 7852.00);

INSERT  INTO @tbl (EmployeeId, EffectiveDate, salary)
VALUES           (00016, getdate() + 1, 7952.00);

INSERT  INTO @tbl (EmployeeId, EffectiveDate, salary)
VALUES           (00016, getdate() + 2, 8052.00);

INSERT  INTO @tbl (EmployeeId, EffectiveDate, salary)
VALUES           (00017, getdate(), 7852.00);

INSERT  INTO @tbl (EmployeeId, EffectiveDate, salary)
VALUES           (00017, getdate() + 1, 7952.00);

INSERT  INTO @tbl (EmployeeId, EffectiveDate, salary)
VALUES           (00018, getdate(), 7852.00);

WITH   cteSalary
AS     (SELECT EmployeeId,
               EffectiveDate,
               salary,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId 
                              ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC) AS rn
        FROM   @tbl)
SELECT a.EmployeeId,
       a.EffectiveDate,
       a.salary,
       b.salary AS 'Previous salary'
FROM   cteSalary AS a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       cteSalary AS b
       ON a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
          AND b.rn = 2
WHERE  a.rn = 1;
```